# How can I tour Serengeti National Park by starting off in Nairobi?

Tags: tanzania, nairobi

What are my options (methods, approximate prices, safety, and duration) in getting to Serengeti National Park from Nairobi, Kenya? Is the only way to take a bus to Arusha, Tanzania and then another bus to the park?

I found some scattered info [here](https://www.safaribookings.com/serengeti/getting-there), [here](http://wikitravel.org/en/Serengeti_National_Park#Get_in), and [here](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Nairobi/Serengeti-National-Park).

**Edits**

I didn't know most Serengeti safari tours start in Arusha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the only way is via Arusha or by private car.

For the route via Arusha you can [book tickets on Busbud](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules/Nairobi,Nairobi,Kenya/Arusha,Arusha,Tanzania) (full disclosure: I work on this project). There you can catch a local bus onward, though these run infrequently, maybe not even daily.

I'm not sure what your intentions once reaching the park are, since there aren't likely to be facilities set-up for access without a car. You may be better off booking a safari directly from Arusha.

Comment: I'm thinking of touring the safari. I didn't know I had to book something that starts in Arusha. Thanks.

Comment: No prob, as @dianod points out there are a number of tour options departing Nairobi as well as from Arusha. My personal experience is with http://www.authentictanzania.com/ who tailored us a great trip, we asked to avoid lodges and stayed in basic places with limited electricity.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to travelling to Arusha and leaving from there is to get a tour that leaves from Nairobi and includes the Serengeti.  This will be more expensive and take longer than busing to Arusha because you'll generally see more than just the Serengeti, but it does match your criteria.

[Example 1](http://www.intrepidtravel.com/tanzania/serengeti-trail-83385)

[Example 2](http://www.intrepidtravel.com/tanzania/serengeti-kilimanjaro-84120)

[Example 3](http://www.peregrineadventures.com/africa/kenya/highlights-kenya-tanzania-2015) (does enter via Arusha)

[Example 4](http://www.geckosadventures.com/africa/kenya/lion-thing-2015) (does enter via Arusha)